# Alamofire - per-request auth tokens - not sure how to approach it

Tags: swift, alamofire

New to Alamofire and I think I've got a grasp of some of the basics, but I'm struggling with one thing. It's got to do with the usual - asynchronous calls and closures.

The service I'm interacting with issues per-request service tokens.

- You get a general user ticket (valid for 24 hours)
- Then, you use that user ticket to request a new service ticket for each request

Workflow winds up being like...

```
 - (Log in service) -> Auth ticket
 --- (Request token service)(supply auth ticket) -> Service request token
 ------ ([some app service] (supply service request token) -> do stuff
```

The service request token is valid for one and only one request. Each individual app service request requires I obtain a new token.

I understand how to do the single auth ticket and I can get the individual request tokens generated, but - from there I'm struggling.  For a given app service call (let's say "search"), would I need to request the new service request token within the search service request method itself (and lather, rinse, repeat for each app service)?

Something like...

```
//search function
func getSearchResults(
  searchParams: [String:AnyObject] , 
  completionHandler: (Result<[SearchResult], NSError>, String?) -> Void) {

  //go ahead and get a ticket
  APIManager.ticketClient.getServiceTicket({ (serviceTicketResult) -> Void in
       var params = searchParams
       params["ticket"] = serviceTicketResult.value

       //run the search request
       Alamofire.request(.GET, requestURI, parameters: params, headers: headers)
      .validate()
      .responseString { response in....
```

Or is there a way I can abstract out the repeated request/response to get the token and incorporated it into somewhere like the Router?

I'm following the example [API Abstraction](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#api-parameter-abstraction) and I'm wondering if I can somehow request the service ticket within the Router?

```
let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)!
let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(result.path))
let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL
//do magical stuff to get request ticket and jam it into result.parameters?
return encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: result.parameters).0
```

Is that just the wrong way to approach it? I'm honestly not even sure how I'd do that without explicitly setting a return type in the ticket-granting service request. Trying to wrap my head around how to think in Alamofire.

Any suggestions much appreciated

Comment: There are a few different approaches, from operations, nested calls, or even property observers. I'm waiting to try this personally, maybe it can help you http://promisekit.org

Comment: Using PromiseKit, RxSwift or some other reactive system is ideal for this sort of "chaining async calls" problem.